# Invoke SP_SSIS_ADDLOGENTRY from within SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am pretty new to the world of SSIS.

For custom logging, I want to pass certain additional variables to SP_SSIS_ADDLOGENTRY proc 
from within SSIS and also want to modify it with my own customized code. Pls let me know :-

1. From where in SSIS is SP_SSIS_ADDLOGENTRY invoked ? So that I can locate and edit it to pass few additional variables from SSIS.
2. I couldnt locate the SP on sql server. Where can i find the SP so that i can modify it to add my own code

*We are using Sql Server 2012.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

sp_ssis_addlogentry and the sysssislog table are added to the database that you are logging to the first time that logging is run.  These are both marked as system objects, so they will appear under the System Stored Procedures and System Tables, respectively.

sp_ssis_addlogentry is executed programatically from SSIS and there is no way to change the way that works.  You can use the `Dts.Events.Fire<Event>` method to log custom entries, but this interface will not allow you to add new columns, for example.

In answer to the inability to customize the in-built logging in SSIS, people often roll their own.  You might add a PostExecute event to the package which calls your own logging proc and captures the additional details you are after, i.e. row counts.  If you capture the executionid, you will be able to tie this to the in-built logging and use your custom logging simply as an extension.

Also, do note, that if you use the project deployment model, the tables which are logged to are in the SSISDB catalog.  They capture more information but are still lacking in some aspects, like row counts.